# How to get all permissions IDs of a permission object in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to list the top permissions a user has, and I know that `discord.Member.guild_permissions` would give me *a* permission ID. I can use a list comprehension like `[perm[0] for perm in user.guild_permissions]` to get all the *string* permissions, but I want to get a list for all the permission *IDs* the member has. How can I be able to do that?

Here is my code so far:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
intents = discord.Intents.all
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', description='- shows this message', intents=intents)
---- snip ----

@bot.command(brief='sends top permissions')
async def user_perms(ctx, member: discord.Member):
    permissions = member.guild_permissions
    permission_list = [perm[0] for perm in permissions] # how do I get a list of all the top permission IDs?
    

bot.run('TOKEN')
```

Answer (score 0):

`Member.guild_permissions` returns a `discord.Permissions` instance which has the `value` attribute

```py
permissions = member.guild_permissions
ids = permissions.value
```

#### Reference:

- [`Permissions.value`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions.value)

Comment: `Permissions.value` returns the value of the *entire* permission, but I want to find the permission ID for all of the permissions a member has. For example, if a member has Administrator and Manage Messages, I want a list that returns [administrator_id, manage_messages_id]